# Recording model train's sound output

Tags: recording

A little backstory for those not in the know. Model trains used to be, for the most part, controlled by varying DC voltage, usually in the 12V range. Over the past 30 years, systems have been developed to use "Digital Command Control", a bipolar AC signal (9-16V, depending) that contains packets in pulse waves. These are decoded by on-board decoders on the model locomotives.

Over the past decade, sound decoders have become more popular with a small on-board speaker. Now, I'm in N scale (1:160) and many of those speakers are as small as 11x16mm and 8 ohm. They have exactly the bass response you'd expect.

What I'd like to do is record the output from this. The last thing I want to do is fry one of these $120 decoders, so I want to figure out how. Can I hardwire the speaker output directly into a 3.5mm mic in on a computer or audio recorder?

Decoder manual is available here: http://www.esu.eu/uploads/tx_esudownloads/51972_LokSound_V40_ESUKG_EN_User-Manual_Edition-4_eBook_03.pdf

If more technical info on the decoder is needed, let me know and I'll try to get it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which decoder(s)?

Comment: A guy who knows! ESU Loksound micro select/4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The LokSound micro V4.0 has a "Class D last stage amplifier with a power output of 3 Watts" into 4 Ω, probably with BTL ('bridge-tied load') output. For 3 W into 4 Ω the rms voltage would be ~3.5 volts. That can easily be divided down to the 1 Vrms or lower required by the computer's LINE input jack.

However the signal first has to be converted from balanced to unbalanced, and it has to be isolated from the sound decoder and DCC track voltages. DCC power is +- 12 V, with the reversals encoding a digital control signal via pulse widths of 58 and 100 uS. This could induce a lot of noise into the signal if the balanced to unbalanced conversion is not done right.

The simplest solution is probably a high impedance audio transformer, perhaps with a low pass filter ahead of it to smooth the class D waveform (normally this occurs inside the speaker, so the amplifier may not have an output filter). The circuit could look something like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM1i2D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1-4 in series with R5 divides the input voltage by 4.8 to produce a maximum input level at the transformer of ~0.7 V rms (slightly less than 0 dBm into 600 Ω). The transformer is a standard 600 Ω line transformer like the [Bourns LM-NP-1001-B1L](https://nz.element14.com/bourns/lm-np-1001-b1l/line-matching-transformer/dp/1929741), typically used in analog MODEMS and FAX machines. These are designed for operation at 300 Hz ~ 10 Khz and normally have poor low frequency response, but with the higher impedance load of the sound card's LINE input it should go below 100 Hz. A high fidelity audio transformer such as the [Vigortronix VTX-101-007](https://nz.element14.com/vigortronix/vtx-101-007/transformer-audio-1-1-1-1/dp/1674305) would work better, but they tend to be more expensive and harder to obtain (depending on where you live, perhaps even impossible right now).

Capacitors C1 and C2 make a 2 pole RC low pass filter with cutoff at ~10 Khz. Hopefully attenuation at the (unknown) class D switching frequency will be enough to remove any interference it might cause.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. A couple days before this reply I had ordered a Shure -50dB attenuator, and it appears to have a very similar circuit to this - at a much higher price than components, of course.